# Awaitable Properties in C#

Tags: c#, properties, async-await

In C#, does it violate best-practices to have Properties of type `Task`, which allow you to `await` the Property?

I verified that the C# compiler allows this code, but I'm curious if this is violates best-practices?

Below is an example showing how to implement an awaitable Property to retrive a SQLite database.

## Sample Code

#### Consuming the awaitable Property in Parent Class

```
public class Database : BaseDatabase
{
    ...

    async Task<List<MyModel>> GetAllData()
    {
        //**** Awaiting a Property ****//
        var databaseConnection = await DatabaseConnectionTask;

        databaseConnection.Table<MyModel>().ToListAsync();
    }

    ...
}
```

#### Creating the awaitable Property in Base Class

```
public abstract class BaseDatabase
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _databaseConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);

    bool _isInitialized;

    //**** Awaitable Property ****//
    protected Task<SQLiteAsyncConnection> DatabaseConnectionTask => GetDatabaseConnection();

    static async Task<SQLiteAsyncConnection> GetDatabaseConnection()
    {
        if (!_isInitialized)
            await Initialize();

        return _databaseConnection;
    }

    static async Task Initialize()
    {
        await _databaseConnection.CreateTableAsync<MyModel>();
        _isInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What purpose does this property serve? Why not just call `GetDatabaseConnection` directly?

Comment: Hey @mason! The code above is just a sample on how to create an awaitable Property in C#. I understand that we can call `GetDatabaseConnection` directly. I posted this question to get feedback from fellow developers about the Pros/Cons of using awaitable Properties. The C# compiler allows it, but I don't think it's a best-practice. Let me know what you think!

Comment: My comment states it already: What purpose does this property serve? I can't really think of a situation where it makes sense to do this. Properties are there to represent the state of an object. If you have to do something long running to get the state, then it doesn't belong in a property, regardless of if it's awaitable or not. That sort of code belongs in a method so that its usage is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a [blog post on the subject](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html).

In summary, properties that *start a new asynchronous operation* are probably not a good design. They are essentially just asynchronous methods in a more awkward syntax.

Your current code is starting a new asynchronous operation each time its `get` accessor is invoked. However, based on the usage, I expect this is a mistake. You probably meant to have a read-only property:

```
protected Task<SQLiteAsyncConnection> DatabaseConnectionTask { get; }
    = GetDatabaseConnection();
```

which will share the task (and connection) among all the methods that read that property.

Read-only `Task` properties are a better than asynchronous getters, but there's still some caveats with them. E.g., `GetDatabaseConnection` is started in the constructor. If that's not desired, then an [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) would be more appropriate.

Also, any time you "cache" a `Task` instance like this (whether using `AsyncLazy<T>` or not), you have to pay particular attention to your error handling. E.g., if the connection fails, then a cached task will cache that exception. You should consider using retries (e.g., Polly) inside your factory method, and/or using something like `AsyncLazyFlags.RetryOnFailure` (if using my `AsyncLazy<T>` type).